# Gulp version 4. Why is it not the 'latest' version?

Tags: npm, gulp, npm-install

I am working on a project which has gulp as a dependency. I am looking at updating it to gulp 4. A quick look at the output of `npm show gulp@latest` shows

```
...
dist-tags:
latest: 3.9.1  next: 4.0.0
...
```

I wonder why the gulp team have left `latest: 3.9.1` and choose `next: 4.0.0`, i.e. `npm install gulp` installs 3.9.1 while to get 4.0.0 one has to ask for `npm install gulp@next`. Why is the default version still 3.9.1? Is version 4.0.0 still not fully supported or something? I have not found anything regarding this on the gulp website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`npm dist-tag`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dist-tag#purpose) docs:

> By default, the latest tag is used by npm to identify the current
>   version of a package, and npm install  (without any @ or
>   @ specifier) installs the latest tag. Typically, projects only
>   use the latest tag for stable release versions, and use other tags for
>   unstable versions such as prereleases.
>
> The next tag is used by some projects to identify the upcoming
>   version.
>
> By default, other than latest, no tag has any special significance to
>   npm itself.

In this case `latest` is `3.x.x` and `next` is `4.x.x` As it is following [semver](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/semantic-versioning), it means that there are backwards **incompatible** changes. If you check [gulpjs.com](https://gulpjs.com/), the link to the documentation brings you to the `3.x.x` docs. It's the authorative version at the moment as set by the gulp maintainers.

Comment: Thanks, you fully answered my question.